# Select the range from first cell used to last cell used in column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro which selects my first cell used in column M (variable is Firstrow). This macro detects the last cell used in column M (variable is lastrow).

I would like that my macro selects from first cell used in column M to last cell used in column M.

I tried:

Range (Firsttrow & "M:M" & lastrow)

but I got an error message

> “Compile error: invalid use of property”

[image]

```
Sub Selectfromfirstrowusedtolastrowusedused()
Dim lastrow, Firstrow As Long
lastrow = ActiveSheet.Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Firstrow = Range("M1").End(xlDown).Row
Debug.Print Firstrow
Debug.Print lastrow
Range (Firsttrow & "M:M" & lastrow)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need

`Range("M" & Firsttrow & ":M" & lastrow).Select`

because it is column then row using Range. An alternative would be

`Range(cells(firstrow,"M"),cells(lastrow,"M")).Select`

Not that you rarely need to [select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C273.0754) anything though.

Also, in this line

`Dim lastrow, Firstrow As Long`

lastrow is declared as a variant so better to do

`Dim lastrow As Long, Firstrow As Long`

Answer (score 1):

The right way to do it would be

`Range("M" & Firsttrow & ":M" & lastrow")`